# How to get one of preceeding elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html structure is like below :

```
<header></header>
<div id="take-113"></div>
<div id="take-114"></div>
<div id="take-115"></div>
```

How can I find same header from each div?

```
$("take-113").prev("header"); // works
$("take-114").prev("header");// doesn't work
$("take-115").prev("header"); // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See jquery [.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

```
$("take-115").prevAll("header:eq(0)");
```

Answer (score 2):

`prev` only selects the previous sibling of the element, you can use `prevAll()` method:

```
$("#take-114").prevAll("header").first();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have more then one header then you can define which one you want to get

```
$("take-113").prevAll("header:first");
$("take-114").prevAll("header:first");
$("take-115").prevAll("header:first");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("take-113").prev("header"); // works
$("take-114").prev("header");// doesn't work
$("take-115").prev("header"); // doesn't work
```

replace this by

```
$("#take-113").prev("header"); 
$("#take-114").prev("header");
$("#take-115").prev("header");
```